# NodeJS/Mongoose - How to reference individual models after concatenation?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, concatenation

I am concatenating two models (Blogs and Events) so I can display all records from both collections in a single forEach loop:

```
const blogs = await Blog.find({});
const events = await Event.find({});
const blogsAndEvents = blogs.concat(events);

blogsAndEvents.forEach(function(blogOrEvent) { etc. etc.
```

However, within the forEach loop, in some cases, I want to still reference the original model it comes from, e.g. 'if Blog, title equals BLOG, if Event, title equals event).  I have a workaround for this where I am using a unique field from each model to determine the underlying model, like this:

```
if (blogOrEvent.blogPost) {
    title = "BLOG"
} elseIf (blogOrEvent.eventDate) {
    title = "EVENT"
}
```

This approach doesn't seem very clean to me though as it relies on their being a unique field in each model.  It there a better way I can access the original underlying model within the loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mongoose documents it can be distinctly verified which `Model` they belong to using `instance of` :

```
  const blogs = await Blog.find({});
  const events = await Event.find({});
  const blogsAndEvents = blogs.concat(events);

  blogsAndEvents.forEach(function (blogOrEvent) {
    if (blogOrEvent instanceof Blog) {
      title = "BLOG";
    } else if (blogOrEvent instanceof Event) {
      title = "EVENT";
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: One further question please...  it seems I cannot access 'instanceof' in my .ejs template, so how would I access the individual models in a forEach loop in the .ejs template directly?

Comment: @Martin Not very familiar with `ejs` templates. Would recommend to ask a separate question outlining the use case and ejs code to have a better visibility from the community and get help. In case u do, point me to the question as well. :)